# Circle CI + Firebase "tslint: not found"

Tags: firebase, circleci

I'm trying to deploy to Firebase through CircleCI, but I keep getting the following error from Circle:

```
tslint: not found
```

The Circle CI config file is [here](https://github.com/dutzi/testkit/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml).

The firebase config file is [here](https://github.com/dutzi/testkit/blob/master/firebase.json).

Answer (score 1):

are u trying to deploy your functions?

If so, notice you are installing everything into the root folder, not the `functions` folder.

I spent like 6 hours on the same issue once... ^^

Take a look at [this](https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-continuous-deploying-with-cloud-build/) scroll down to `Create the cloud build configuration file` notice the dir is `functions` instead of the root.

Changing your `dir` configuration on the circle file should do the trick